# iTunes Home Sharing only works one way between 2 Windows XP PC's on the same LAN

Tags: itunes, firewall, port, home-sharing

Both PC's have the latest iTunes installed.  PC (A) can "see" that there is a shared library "B library" but attempts to connect to it return this error message:

```
The shared library "{Username}'s Library" is not responding (-3259)
Check that any firewall software running on either the shared
computer or this computer has been set to allow communication
on port 3689.
```

however the reverse works fine. e.g. PC (B) can "see" shared library "A library" and can access all content.

**Notes:**

- Both PC's have Home Sharing enabled (turned off/on several times to verify).
- Both PC's have Windows Firewall turned on, but in the exceptions tab, iTunes is allowed, and Port 3689 is also added as a firewall exception (just in case)
- Both iTunes accounts have been "authorized" on both PC's
- Both PC's connect via LAN via D-Link DIR-615 router.  In the advanced application rules, iTunes has also been added to allow traffic on port 3689 un-hindered.

Is there any other magical setting/configuration option that I should be aware of and set in order to get this to work? I could care less about sharing apps etc. I just want the music sharing to work.

**Update: Solved!**

- It turns out on PC (B) there were multiple accounts set up. 1 of the accounts had the checkbox *checked* under the Windows firewall "On" option which states "No exceptions" thus even though it was added to the exception list on the main user account, this other account was blocking access.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to firewall, just turn it off and try again. If you have an AntiVirus running on your pc- stop it also. Hope these tips helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that iTunes isn't frozen.
If not, check to make sure that port 3689 is open to local traffic, not just web traffic in general. Make sure it stays awake. You need to have all the account authorizations for all the DRM'd music in both iTunes accounts and to have home sharing logged into the same account as both, I do believe it needs to be an account authorized on both sides. Also, check for other firewalls you may have forgotten about and make sure that it's taken care of as well.

Comment: understood - iTunes at both ends is definitely alive and interactive. AFAIK, there is *nothing* blocking port 3689.  I simply can't connect 1 way.  All music is DRM free mp3's, both accounts are authorized on both sides. AFAIK I only have the windows firewall, and my router firewall.

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than 1 account on a PC, **ALL** of the accounts must have the firewall open for port 3689.

Unfortunately as I found out, it turns out on PC (B) there were multiple accounts set up. 1 of the accounts had the checkbox checked under the Windows firewall "On" option which states "No exceptions" thus even though it was added to the exception list on the main user account, this other account was blocking access.